# Computer won't post, Dell Vostro 200

Tags: post, dell-vostro

After trying to insert an expansion card and changing the thermal paste my PC won't post, the fans spin incessantly and the power button turns blue, no beeps, the monitor is on.

Comment: What expansion card? Is it still inserted? Does it work if you remove it?

Comment: It was a USB port expansion card

Comment: I removed the wifi and this other one , still not posting

Comment: I think it may be the CPU, I just changed the thermal paste, how can I be sure it was that?

Comment: Try to re-seat it and visually inspect it for any obvious damage. Also take  a closer look at the socket, some pins may be bent. Unplug and re-plug all PSU cables.

Comment: OK, give me a minute

Comment: I think I found the problem, while taking apart the cpu I took out one of the RAM sticks, it was badly reconnected, gonna try booting it now

Comment: Yes... That was it... Sorry... Anyways, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking it the HDD I was taking it the CPU fan to see if the pins had a problem when I realized that the RAM wasn't properly connected.

Then I had to take out and reconnect one of the sticks and now it's working properly.